# data not rendering using handlebars and expressnjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi i am making an application using express.js and handlebars. I am using the get method to get the data of employees when user enters http://localhost:3000/id/2 in the browser. As id is 2 so it should fetch the data and render it using handlebars. My method of getting is working fine otherwise but once i use it to render it doesnot work. Although i have done similar rendering for other methods and they work fine.I have checked in headers it returns 304 status code error. how to fix it.

```
  //My express get method:

     app.get('/id/:id1', function(req, res) {
    res.render('employee', 
    {idData: employees.lookupById(req.params.id1) 
     });
    });
```

//employees.lookupByID()method which i am using in the main file via require-Mod

```
       var _ = require('underscore');

       var data = [
       {id:1, firstName:'John',lastName:'Smith'},
        {id:2, firstName:'Jane',lastName:'Smith'}
          ];
      module.exports.lookupById = function (pid) {

      if( _.where(data, {id:pid}))
       {
          return _.where(data, {id:pid})
       }

     else{

       return 0;
        }
     };

     // My rendering view of employee.handlebars
     <hr/>
     <ul>
       {{#each idData}}
        <li>{{this.id}}</li>
        <li>{{this.firstName}}</li>
         <li>{{this.lastName}}</li>
      {{/each}}
     </ul>
    <b>Thanks</b>
```

//here only Thanks gets render on my html page and the array data isnt't return

So how do i go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
```

Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client. Optional parameters:

```
// if a callback is specified, the rendered HTML string has to be sent explicitly
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
    res.send(html);
});
```

can you explain better what you are trying to accomplish? 
thanks

Comment: when the user send get request like url/id/2... i am trying to fetch data from an array with id 2 and render it on html page. I have other methods they are working fine but this one isn't Does error 304 status code has to do with it.